# Pentadactyl: Search several sites at one command

Tags: vimperator, pentadactyl

Consider a problem of searching several wikis at one command. Here's a possible solution. If one'd add the following to the `.pentadactylrc`:

```
javascript <<EOF
    dactyl.searchWikis = function (selection) {
        let parsedSelection = selection.replace(/^\s*/, "" ).replace(/\s*$/, "" ).replace(/\s+/g, "+" );
        dactyl.execute( ":tabopen http://www.scholarpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=" + selection);
        dactyl.execute( ":tabopen http://en.citizendium.org/wiki?title=Special:Search&search=" + selection);
    };
EOF

:command wikiSearch -nargs=* -js dactyl.searchWikis(<args>)
```

That should've solved it - but the problem is - that this way Pentadactyl doesn't see the JS code. I.e. new command wikiSearch doesn't appear. Can You fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to add your function on the `userContext`, rather than on `dactyl`.

e.g.

```
javascript <<EOF
    userContext.searchWikis = function (selection) {
        commands.execute("tabopen http://www.scholarpedia.org/wiki/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=" + selection);
        commands.execute("tabopen http://en.citizendium.org/wiki?title=Special:Search&search=" + selection);
    };
EOF
```

I took the `parsedSelection` line out, as selection doesn't appear to come in as a string.

Also try removing the angle-brackets from `<args>`:

```
command wikiSearch -nargs=* -js userContext.searchWikis(args)
```

Comment: I wanted to award You - but did something wrong. I'll award You at the end of the bounty.

Comment: @Adobe that's how bounties work. you start a bounty, you can award the amount after 2 days of starting the bounty. [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

Comment: @Adobe Thanks, glad it helped.  Pentadactyl is a fantastic piece of software.